# How to retrieve filenames for a BizTalk Purchase Order

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am very much new to BizTalk Server, one of our clients want to know the filename of the purchase order given by them. Its already been processed in the system through BizTalk Server and the client has received the purchase order, but he wants to get the filename of that purchase order (or in short the whole file for that purchase order) as there was some issue with the cost.

How can I get it or what are the steps for doing it?

Note: I am new to BizTalk so not much experieced in asking questions related to it. But if you have any questions which I can answer, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Is this a one time request or are they asking to be able to see the file name going forward?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the received filename inside an Orchestration you need to use the message context property **BTS.ReceivedFileName**.

e.g.

```
   FileName = MessageName(BTS.ReceivedFileName);
```

If you want to set the filename in a send port to the received filename (or rather to what is in BTS.ReceivedFilename as you can set it yourself) then you need to use one of the predefined send [Macros](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8823.biztalk-server-list-of-macros.aspx), in this case **%SourceFileName%**

If you want to see the filename in the BizTalk administration console, then you need to look at the message context and look for the ReceivedFileName property.

Comment: Hi - I think that should be MessageName(FILE.ReceivedFileName).